# Cannot operate with array as array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm creating an array like this

```
var p1_s1 = {
            'title': 'p1_s1', 'titleDisplayed': 'p1_s1', 'type': 'numbers', 'page':1,'strings': 1, 'length': 7, 'placeholder':'0000000', 'painted':'black', 'notPainted':'#ffe485', 'left':410, 'top':161, 'width':394, 'height':144,
            'ids':[
                    ['path5472','path5440','path5488','path5520','path5504','path5456','path5536'],
                    ['path5360','path5328','path5376','path5408','path5392','path5344','path5424'],
                    ['path5584','path5552','path5600','path5632','path5616','path5568','path5648'],
                    ['path4912','path4880','path4928','path4960','path4944','path4896','path4976'],
                    ['path5024','path4992','path5040','path5072','path5056','path5008','path5088'],
                    ['path5136','path5104','path5152','path5184','path5168','path5120','path5200'],
                    ['path5248','path5216','path5264','path5296','path5280','path5232','path5312']
                    ]
    };
```

Then, in script code i call this variable

```
...
var ids = p1_s1['ids'];
        for(var i = ids.length;i>=0;i--)
        {
            drawOneNumber( ids[i], parseInt(value[i]) );
        }
...
function drawOneNumber( place, number )
{
    number = numberToSegments( number );
    console.log(place);
    for(var i=0;i<number.length;i++)
    {
        console.log( place[i] );
    }
    ...
}
```

On string `console.log(place);` i see array in console as it should be.

```
(7) […]
​0: "path5248"
​1: "path5216"
​2: "path5264"
​3: "path5296"
​4: "path5280"
​5: "path5232"
​6: "path5312"
​length: 7
​
```

But on string `console.log( place[i] );` I got an error

```
TypeError: place is undefined
```

Same situation with

```
place.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

Code `Array.isArray(place);` returns true, but I cannot manipulate this variable lika an array.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I am not seeing the definition of "place" anywhere in this code. Your variable is called p1_s1 and it is not an array

Comment: a little missprint, string `var ids = place['ids'];` should be like this `var ids = p1_s1['ids'];`

Comment: Try :   `for(var i = ids.length-1;i>=0;i--)`

Comment: does that solve your issue? Because as the error suggests, place is indeed not defined. If not please update the question with the correct error message

Comment: @sinanspd `place` is defined (it's the first argument). @user11604311 where is `value[i]` coming from?

Comment: @MaximeGirou damn, it worked. What a stupid mistake (( Thank you a lot!

Comment: @BrandonHill `place` is *declared*, since it's a parameter, but the error suggests its value is `undefined`.

Comment: @user11604311 it happends ;) ! i wrote an answer bellow

Comment: @BrandonHill he originally had a typo where he was referencing place outside of the function, OP edited the question accordingly, I was clarifying that the typo indeed wasn't also present in the code

Comment: @VLAZ/@sinanspd understood, sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem come from the for loop

You defined 
If you array is a length of 5, the last element will be accesible at the 4th place.

As you defined `i = ids.length` and try to access `ids[i]`, it will be undefined and the variable `place`in your drawOneNumber function will be undefined too.

Example:

```js
const arr = ["foo", "bar", "youhou"];

console.log(arr.length);
console.log(arr[arr.length]);
```

Try : `for(var i = ids.length -1 ;i>=0;i--)` instead.